# How to make mutiple lines in Regular expressions

Tags: regex, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-parsing

i want to make a regular expression for web scraping

how can i search for multiple line result :

for exemple  this is my Html

```
    <div id="cn-centre-col-inner">

    <p>sothing her</p>
     ...
    </div>

    <div id="ok"> ..</div>
```

i want to find a regular expression that gieves me this result :

```
    <div id="cn-centre-col-inner">

    <p>sothing her</p>
     ...
    </div>
```

Comment: [It's a trap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454z)

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: i'm using  C# langage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not the best tool to do this, you should use a html parser instead.

Suppose that you have this regex:

```
(?s)<div id="cn-centre-col-inner">.*?<\/div>
```

You will be able to capture what you want like:

```
<div id="cn-centre-col-inner">

    <p>sothing her</p>
    ...
</div>
```

But, you can't ensure that the first closing div is the right one. For instance, for this case:

```
<div id="cn-centre-col-inner">

    <p>sothing her</p>
    ...
    <div>something inner 1</div>
    <div>something inner 2</div>
</div>
<div id="ok"> ..</div>
```

You will lose content and you will only capture:

```
<div id="cn-centre-col-inner">

    <p>sothing her</p>
    ...
    <div>something inner 1</div>
```

Like this:
[image]

This is a good example to show why regex shouldn't be use to parse complex html. I strongly recommend you to use a html parser.

If you are **ultra sure** that your div `cn-centre-col-inner` has not embedded divs, then you can go ahead with the regex above. Actually you can use capturing group to get all the content within the div:

```
(?s)<div id="cn-centre-col-inner">(.*?)<\/div>
                                  ^---^--- notice the parentheses
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After reading the warnings about regexs and html, and if it is just for a specific task, you can try something dirty like that:

```
(<div[^>]*id="cn-centre-col-inner.*</div>)\n<div id="ok"
```